# Oracle SQL Developer - looping/debugging cursor behavior

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

This is a pretty odd issue I'm trying to wrap my head around. In this code someone else wrote, they are appending to a string inside of two for loops, one is looping the cursor `cKitToFind`, and the inner loop is looping one time per quantity of the item. The problem I'm having, is that the variable `vKitToFind1` *is* being appended with data, but every time that I hover over `rKitToFind`, every value inside that object is null (for whatever reason, the window that shows the values of `rKitToFind` is appearing on my other monitor and I can't drag it over into view for the gif to show). So while `rKitToFind` has null values for all of its fields as far as the debugger will let me see, I can tell that somehow there are actually values contained, since the string `vKitToFind1` is appending to itself based solely on `rKitToFind's` contents. I can provide more code/context if needed, but I tried to keep what I included very specific so that it's as least confusing as possible.

Had to keep the gif relatively short (under 2mb for upload). What I'm trying to show, is that the value of `vKitToFind1` is being appended to, but on the other monitor, the object it is appending based on, `rKitToFind`... every field in that is null.

[image]

Comment: what is rKitToFind - is is just a local varchar2? Or is it declared as a PL/SQL user defined TYPE? If the latter, make sure the TYPE/TYPE Body is ALSO compiled for DEBUG

Comment: It's declared like [this](https://imgur.com/jzeauEM). Good news as an aside, I managed to figure out the issue I was trying to resolve that involves this code... so for now the fire is put out, now it's just curiosity in terms of why this happened.